# Still having trouble understanding gravitational lensing

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, gravitational-lensing

The normal diagram used to explain gravitational lensing shows a two-dimensional plane that is deflected by a heavy weight. This is a two dimensional description that requires an extra dimension to complete it. My question is does real three dimensional space require an extra dimension to explain gravitational lensing. I know that time is somehow involved but surely a spacial dimension would be required.

Comment: I would recommend going through a traditional GR course, which should be clear. There are many other questions on phys.SE on gravitational lensing and so this seems to be redundant.

Comment: Can you post an example of a diagram showing a  " two dimensional plane that is deflected by a heavy weight"?

Comment: As soon as we learned from GR that a gravitational body can bend light paths, gravitational lensing automatically follows as a corollary.  Where is the conceptual difficulty?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99511/2451 and links therein.